# :asc in neovim with 8-bit encoding (latin2)

Tags: vim, neovim

When a file in latin2-encoding is opened in neovim with ":e! ++enc=latin2" everything is displayed correctly.

What I don't understand is how the ":asc" command works in this situation. e.g. for the Romanian character Ţ the following is displayed:

```
<Ţ> 354, Hex 0162, Oct 542, Digr T,
```

I think 354 comes from the Unicode representation. But latin2 is an 8-bit character set. The character value is 222.

Why the asc-command does not display the 8-bit value in this situation?

Comment: `542` is the correct octal conversion of the hexadecimal `0162`, which is the correct hexadecimal conversion of the decimal `354`. I am not sure why you expect `222`, here, or where, as the values displayed are not relative to the current `fileencoding`.

Comment: fileencoding in vim is iso-8859-2 in this case. The maximum value for a 8-bit characterset is 0xff or 255. In this case the letter Ţ has the value

Comment: …which is irrelevant. The output of `:help :ascii` doesn't change with the `fileencoding`.

Comment: So this is intentional? I don't understand why. I mean the character is stored as 0xde that is 222 in decimal.

Comment: Intentional? Certainly. The character is stored as whatever it is supposed to be stored as *in the current `:help 'encoding'` used internally by Vim*. If both Vim and your terminal emulator are set up to use `iso-8859-2`, then the value displayed [is the one you expect](https://i.imgur.com/VaHBGW6.png). If not, then you get a different value: with `encoding` set to `utf-8` in a terminal emulator set up for `utf-8`, you get `354, Hex 0162…`.

Answer (score 0):

The `++enc` parameter (or `&fileencoding` option) is only used during the conversion of file contents to (or from) global Vim's internal encoding which is set by `&encoding` option (it is normally equal to UTF-8 in modern Vim and cannot be changed in Neovim at all).

So there is no more latin-2 while editing the file. And `ascii` command will never display it.